# Rviz fixed frame error

Tags: rviz, moveit, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all and thanks for checking this out.

I have made a [MoveIT! package](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/av9bex3qcr32c53/AAC7zVd_UlvtcwLoQ-ywcqGBa) using my [urdf](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9tvvpqykwnmcz5b/AADa8nZ3-S-MusJ4fIMMN9H1a/urdf/iarm_ed.urdf) and went through the Setup Assistant tabs accordingly. After launching my robot I can motion plan and incorporate a scene object to be planned around, but the Global Status is giving me this error. I believe it has to do with the virtual joint set up but I'm not entirely sure.

> No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [base_link] does not exist

The base_link is the first link in my robot and the child of the [virtual joint](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jd91m3mc4q9g28a/i_arm.srdf). When I add the TF display to Rviz and expand it, it's empty. This is preventing me from using rostopic echo /tf (where, right now, the output is a repeating empty Transform [] ) and also using rosbag record which I would like to use to record some simple paths for playback later.

Can someone tell me if this is in fact a virtual joint error or perhaps somewhere else I need to be looking? I am new to ROS so any links would be appreciated.

Respectfully,

Jordan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186962/rviz-fixed-frame-error/) by [JoSo](https://answers.ros.org/users/18857/joso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution for me was to declare both the parent frame and child frame as base_link in the SRDF.

```
<virtual_joint name="fixed_frame" type="fixed" parent_frame="base_link" child_link="base_link" />
```

This removed the Global Status error, now saying "OK" and the TF tree is populated! Moving on to bigger and harder things

---

Originally posted by [JoSo](https://answers.ros.org/users/18857/joso/) with karma: 120 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1